# elixir dependency resolution failed, when added stripity_stripe 2.0

Tags: elixir

I had an umbrella project, I tried to add stripity_stripe 2.0 to my project, but "hackney" version is conflicted with the ones that are in the project. I got

```
Failed to use "hackney" (versions 1.7.1, 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1) because
  deps/bamboo/mix.exs requires ~> 1.7
  ex_aws (version 2.0.2) requires 1.6.3 or 1.6.5 or 1.7.1 or 1.8.6 or ~> 1.9
  httpoison (version 0.11.2) requires ~> 1.8.0


Failed to use "hackney" (version 1.8.6) because
  deps/bamboo/mix.exs requires ~> 1.7
  ex_aws (version 2.0.2) requires 1.6.3 or 1.6.5 or 1.7.1 or 1.8.6 or ~> 1.9
  httpoison (version 0.11.2) requires ~> 1.8.0
  stripity_stripe (version 2.0.0) requires ~> 1.12.1
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Downgrade `stripity_stripe` _or_ upgrade `hackney` _or_ enforce `mix` to not cross-check versions (not recommended.)

Comment: i can't downgrade stripity_stripe, because the old version doesn't have the feature that i want.  I tried to upgrade hackney, but then my Httpoison(require 1.8 hackney) and tzada(require 1.0 hackney) give error.

Comment: What do you expect from us? To fix the dependencies in all these packages? If you need this particular feature you are going to meet the dependencies. There is no magic.

Comment: You can try to use `override: true`, in your stripity_stripe dep declaration tuple, since it's the one that requires the most recent version. You then need to check that all other deps behave correctly